# Overfilling of Stack and Queue Capacity (c++)

Tags: c++, stack, queue

After many hours of research, reading, going over sample codes... I am stuck (or fried).  I have a memory leak which dumps nothing into my Stack and Queue 'lists'.  The premise is that I am trying to create find if a word or phrase is a palindrome by using Stacks & Queues.  When using just a word to test my program, the stack & queue 'lists' fill up.  I can fix it for a word... but it needs to work for a phrase.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

#include "Stack.h"
#include "stack.cpp"
#include "Queue.h"
#include "queue.cpp"

void blankspace(char *s, char *t);

int main(void)
{
    Stack palinS;
    Queue palinQ;
    char mess[80];
    char bmess[80];
    int i;
    int n;
    int j;
    i = 0;
    n = 0;
    j = 0;

    cout << "Please enter a word or phrase: ";
    cin >> mess;

    blankspace(mess, bmess);

    while (bmess != NULL){
        palinS.push(bmess[i]);
        palinQ.enqueue(bmess[i]);
        i++;
    }

    n = sizeof(bmess);
    while (!palinS.empty()){
        palinS.top();
        palinQ.front();
        if (palinS.top() == palinQ.front())
            j++;
        palinS.pop();
        palinQ.dequeue();
    }

    if (j++ == n){
        cout << "  You have a palindrome!!!";
    }
    else {
        cout << "  SORRY... The word/phrase is NOT a palindrome.";
    }

    return (0);
}

void blankspace(char *s, char *t)
{
    while (*s != '\0'){
        if (*s != ' ') *t = *s;
        t++;
        s++;
    }
```

Comment: Stepping through your code in a debugger is usually the next step for a programmer in your position.  Have you tried it?

Comment: `while (bmess != NULL){
        palinS.push(bmess [i]);
        palinQ.enqueue(bmess [i]);
        i++;
    }`

Well to begin with, you are checking if bmess is NULL, but you are pushing characters from that array onto your stack/queue. So that should go for forever until you overstep your array and undefined behavior happens. That's at least one problem, that would be caught with a debugger.

In other words, `bmess` will always be `&bmess[0]` which should never be null as long as something didn't go wrong when the function was called.

Comment: Your `blankspace` function is not complete, at least the code posted.

Comment: Yes, in the code shown in blankspace is missing the cut of t pushing the '\0' char. If not present, may be the origin of error.

Comment: std::string, std::array would catch a lot of the bugs you probably have - not to mention std::deque instead your own :)

Comment: @DrewDormann Yes, but it tells me that the signal SIGBUS, Bus error occurs when trying to fill the Stack & Queue.  So I know I'm overfilling it.  I just don't know how to correct it for phrases.

Comment: @RyanP  Thank you!!!  I see my error now.  It is one of those things where you either have to walk away from the program or have someone else see it to notice your mistakes.

Comment: For testing, you may use std::stack and std:queue and replace them by your implementations afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@RyanP really deserves credit for this answer.  
After looking at his suggestion, when I fixed the code to...

```
while (bmess [i] != '/O'){
    palinS.push(bmess [i]);
    palinQ.front(bmess [i]);
    i++;
    }
```

That solved my problem of the never-ending Stack & Queue 'list' creation.  Thanks for all the comments!